# Vimeo API: How to list videos from "root" folder?

Tags: directory, vimeo

API https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

I am able to retrieve list of videos from a specific folder.
But how to get a list of the videos in the "root" library folder?
I know the endpoint "/me/videos" but this would give me ALL videos, what I don't want.